# Completar tabela com loop usando jquery

Tags: jquery

Nesta tabela:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>marca</th>
            <th>ano</th>
            <th>cor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Como fazer um loop em jquery para inserir isto dentro do tbody?

```
        <tr>
            <td>fiat</td>
            <td>2001</td>
            <td>verde</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ford</td>
            <td>2002</td>
            <td>azul</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>VW</td>
            <td>2003</td>
            <td>preto</td>
        </tr>
```

Os dados estão dentro de um objeto. Ex:

```
0: {marca: "fiat", ano: "2001", cor:"verde"}
1: {marca: "ford", ano: "2002", cor:"azul"}
2: {marca: "VW", ano: "2003", cor:"preto"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o método `append` ou `appendTo`. Como jQuery já faz o parse de suas strings para HTML, você só precisa escrever a string no devido formato, e depois anexar num elemento que você busca com o jQuery.

```js
var carros = [
  { marca: "fiat", ano: "2001", cor:"verde" }, 
  { marca: "ford", ano: "2002", cor:"azul" }, 
  { marca: "VW", ano: "2003", cor:"preto" }
]

var htmlCarros = carros.map(carro => 
  `<tr>
    <td>${carro.marca}</td>
    <td>${carro.ano}</td>
    <td>${carro.cor}</td>
  </tr>`
)

$('#minha_tabela').append(htmlCarros)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>marca</th>
      <th>ano</th>
      <th>cor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="minha_tabela">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ficou perfeito. Muito obrigado!